# How can I use putchar to print numbers from 0 to 20 (or more)?

Tags: integer, digits, putchar

am looking on how to print digits for 0 to 20 and more with puchar

i tried using putchar('0' + 48) is just printing from 0 to 9, finding it hard to do that is there any help please, i have also tried  constructing the questions but it seems heard to do, can someone help

Comment: `i tried using putchar('0' + 48) is just printing from 0 to 9` Well thats because 0 to 9 are _the only digits_. If you want to print, for example, `10`, you need to print __two__ digits, `1` and `0`.

Comment: and please how can i  print two digit 1 and 0

Comment: The same way you print one digit, just twice.